# Finding mean NDVI value for sub-districts within feature of shapefile between 1994 and 2011

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, csv, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to export as a CSV the mean NDVI values for the sub-districts contained within the NAME_3 feature of my shapefile. Currently I have the following code, but I am not being able to export it with one column per year (between 1994 and 2011):

```
var shp4 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/dermont/GADMVGrassSimplify');

Map.addLayer(shp4, {}, 'My Polygon');
var districts = shp4.filter(filter);
var districtsindo = shp4.select('NAME_3');


var startYear = 1994
var endYear = 2011

var means = ee.Image(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
  .iterate(
    function(year, acc) {
      return ee.Image(acc).addBands(
        yearlyMeans(ee.Number(year))
      )
    },
    ee.Image([])
  )
)

var ndviPerdistrict = means.reduceRegions({
  collection: districtsindo,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().forEachBand(means),
  scale: 30
})

function removegeo(feature) {
  feature = feature.setGeometry(null);
  return feature
}


 
 var ndvi_district = ndviPerdistrict.map(removegeo);   


var columns = ['district'].concat(sequence(startYear, endYear))

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndvi_district, 
  description: 'ndviPerParish',
  selectors: columns
})


function yearlyMeans(year) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')

  
  var landsat = ee.ImageCollection(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T2_TOA"))
    .filterBounds(districtsindo)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)

  var addNDVI = function(image) {
    return image
      .normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3'])
      .rename(year.format('%d')) // Rename NDVI band to the current year
  }

  return landsat.map(addNDVI).mean()
}

// Create client-side sequence
function sequence(from, to) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: to - from + 1})
    .map(function (_, i) {
      return i + from
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not sharing your asset so, I had to create an arbitrary **shp4** variable as it is specified in my [complete code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/916e738daa0c36792aa2b6c6eb06980e). An extract of it, with slightly modifications compared with your code, looks as follows:

```
var feat1 = ee.Feature(geometry).set('NAME_3', 'district1');
var feat2 = ee.Feature(geometry2).set('NAME_3', 'district2');
var feat3 = ee.Feature(geometry3).set('NAME_3', 'district3');

//var shp4 = ee.FeatureCollection('users/dermont/GADMVGrassSimplify');

var shp4 = ee.FeatureCollection([feat1, feat2, feat3]);

Map.addLayer(shp4, {}, 'My Polygon');
//var districts = shp4.filter(filter);
var districtsindo = shp4.select('NAME_3');

print(districtsindo);

var startYear = 1994
var endYear = 2011

var means = ee.Image(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, endYear)
  .iterate(
    function(year, acc) {
      return ee.Image(acc).addBands(
        yearlyMeans(ee.Number(year))
      )
    },
    ee.Image([])
  )
)

var ndviPerdistrict = means.reduceRegions({
  collection: districtsindo,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().forEachBand(means),
  scale: 30
})

function removegeo(feature) {
  feature = feature.setGeometry(null);
  return feature
}


 
 var ndvi_district = ndviPerdistrict.map(removegeo);   


var columns = ['district'].concat(sequence(startYear, endYear))

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: ndvi_district, 
  description: 'ndviPerParish',
  //selectors: columns
})


function yearlyMeans(year) {
  var startDate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
  var endDate = startDate.advance(1, 'year')

  
  var landsat = ee.ImageCollection(ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T2_TOA"))
    .filterBounds(districtsindo)
    .filterDate(startDate, endDate)

  var addNDVI = function(image) {
    return image
      .normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3'])
      .rename(year.format('%d')) // Rename NDVI band to the current year
  }

  return landsat.map(addNDVI).mean()
}

// Create client-side sequence
function sequence(from, to) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: to - from + 1})
    .map(function (_, i) {
      return i + from
    })
}
```

After running above code in GEE code editor, I got following CSV file.

[image]

It can be observed "one column per year (between 1994 and 2011)"; as you expect.

If in your case you are not being able to export the CSV probably there are one or more districts without any information and you should fix it.